# how exclude the end character in regex expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this problem: from list of this `<html>` tag:

```
<td class="pthtdd"><a target="_blank" href="http://address.info">address.info</a>
<td class="pthtdd"><a target="_blank" href="http://address1.com">address1.com</a>
<td class="pthtdd"><a target="_blank" href="http://address2.de">address2.de</a>
<td class="pthtdd"><a target="_blank" href="http://address3.co.uk/">address3.co.uk</a>
```

I want select with regex expression only `http://address.info` or `address1.com` or `address2.de ecc`. I have written this regex: `http:.{1,}?"` but there is `"` at end. I can select all without `"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

`http:[^"]+`

`[^"]` will match any char but `"`.